# How do I make my VSIX file compatible with both VS11 and VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, visual-studio-sdk

How can I make my VSIX file compatible with both Visual Studio 11 and Visual Studio 2010? I'm handing my VSIX file along with all its dependencies to a friend of mine, and when he opens it, he's getting the error "The extension manifest is invalid".

When I open it on my machine (the same machine that built the extension) it works just fine.

What do I do here?

Comment: Here is the best answer I found on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22688894/27194

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to build your extension using VS 2010 and the VS 2010 SDK to support both VS10 and VS11. In your VSIXManifest, you should add the following under `<SupportedProducts>`:

```
<VisualStudio Version="11.0">
  <Edition>Pro</Edition>
</VisualStudio>
```