# vsixmanifest for all: VS 2010, 2012 and 2013

Tags: visual-studio, manifest, vsix, vsixmanifest

I'm using VSIX Manifest Designer under VS2013. I've added **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro** product identifier and ***[10.0,13.0)*** version range to install targets. Despite that fact, I still don't see my VS2010 Professional as an available installation target:

[image]

The source.extension.vsixmanifest file content is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema-design/2011">
  <Metadata>
    <Identity Id="ae98c9e5-8e14-4c92-b45a-c4fd24a49123" Version="1.0" Language="en-US" Publisher="whosoever" />
    <DisplayName>MyExtension</DisplayName>
    <Description xml:space="preserve">whosoever</Description>
    <MoreInfo>http://www.myextension.com</MoreInfo>
    <License>LICENSE.txt</License>
    <Icon>icon.png</Icon>
    <PreviewImage>screenshot.png</PreviewImage>
  </Metadata>
  <Installation InstalledByMsi="false">
    <InstallationTarget Version="[10.0,13.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
  </Installation>
  <Dependencies>
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" d:Source="Manual" Version="4.5" />
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.11.0" DisplayName="Visual Studio MPF 11.0" d:Source="Installed" Version="11.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="%CurrentProject%" Path="|%CurrentProject%;PkgdefProjectOutputGroup|" />
  </Assets>
</PackageManifest>
```

What should be changed to enable installation of this extension to VS2010, 2012 and 2013?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you have is the version 2 VSIX manifest, which is not compatible with Visual Studio 2010. Later Visual Studio versions respect version 1 of the manifest, so in order to support all 3 Visual Studio versions with a single manifest, you'll have to convert it to v1.0  manually (and make sure NOT to edit it with VS2012+, otherwise it will be converted back to v2.0).

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Vsix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2010">
  <Identifier Id="ae98c9e5-8e14-4c92-b45a-c4fd24a49123">
    <Name>MyExtension</Name>
    <Author>whosoever</Author>
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <Description xml:space="preserve">Your decription.</Description>
    <Locale>1033</Locale>
    <SupportedProducts>
      <VisualStudio Version="10.0">
        <Edition>Pro</Edition>
      </VisualStudio>
      <VisualStudio Version="11.0">
        <Edition>Pro</Edition>
      </VisualStudio>
      <VisualStudio Version="12.0">
        <Edition>Pro</Edition>
      </VisualStudio>
    </SupportedProducts>
    <SupportedFrameworkRuntimeEdition MinVersion="4.0" />
  </Identifier>
  <Content>
    <VsPackage>|%CurrentProject%;PkgdefProjectOutputGroup|</VsPackage>
    <MefComponent>|%CurrentProject%|</MefComponent>
  </Content>
</Vsix>
```

You don't have to specify all product editions (called SKUs), `Pro` is enough, if, say, `Ultimate` is installed, it will be displayed instead.

Comment: If you open a version 1 vsixmanifest file in 2012+, it just opens as an XML file (without the designer). I've never had it try to convert the file.

Comment: @280Z28 Yes, you're right. I meant opening it with the VSIX Manifest editor. It will append the v2 schema inside the file. Not replacing the v1 one, but not reading it either.

Comment: This answer just rocks! Can't believe they changed the schema in a way that things must be finally done manually as long as you need to support VS2010 (this is the opposite of rocks)!

Comment: How can i add Support for VS2015? 

Is this correct:

`<VisualStudio Version="14.0">
      <Edition>Enterprise</Edition>
      <Edition>Pro</Edition>
</VisualStudio>
`

Comment: @brighty yup, that looks correct. You can even specify `<Edition>Community</Edition>` in 2015, to have your extension installable in the [free* community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) edition as well.

Comment: @Igal
Thanks for this hint!

Comment: Note that this appears to apply with the release of VS2017 which uses VSIX format 3. Building a VSIX with VS2017, it doesn't seem possible to target VS2015 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

It is working pretty good (*Thanks a lot to Igal*), if the VSIX is developed in VS 2012, and installed in VS 2015. However, the reverse is not working (means developed in VS 2015 and try to install in VS 2012)
After analyzed Activitylog .xml, i found a work around

*Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.*

**Workaround I did** 
Remove VisualStudio.Shell.14.0 and Install  VisualStudio.Shell.11.0 using Package manager console (*Install-Package VSSDK.Shell.11*), and installed in VS 2012. Now Working as expected