# Why can my VisualStudio extension not be found in VS 2013 gallery search (but in VS 2010 and VS 2012)?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

After testing and uploading release 2.4 of my extension [SwitchStartupProject](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4e1be8c-b2dd-4dec-b273-dd88f8818571) ([source code](https://bitbucket.org/thirteen/switchstartupproject/src/92fb357a9b7a7eb6abcdeaad8f0c99fc6367c075/SwitchStartupProject?at=version%202.4)) to the Visual Studio Gallery, I noticed that in **VS 2013** it neither appears in the extension search results when searching with appropriate keywords (e.g. `switch startup`), nor does it show up as available update when an earlier version of it is already installed.

But the extension works in VS 2013 when its VSIX file is downloaded and installed. Also the Visual Studio Gallery page shows that it supports VS 2013. And in VS 2012 and VS 2010 both search and update indication works.

The extension supports VS versions 2010, 2012, 2013 (and 2014 CTP) [using a version 1 VSIX manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688715/vsixmanifest-for-all-vs-2010-2012-and-2013):

```
...
<SupportedProducts>
  <VisualStudio Version="10.0">
    <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
    <Edition>Premium</Edition>
    <Edition>Pro</Edition>
  </VisualStudio>
  <VisualStudio Version="11.0">
    <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
    <Edition>Premium</Edition>
    <Edition>Pro</Edition>
  </VisualStudio>
  <VisualStudio Version="12.0">
    <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
    <Edition>Premium</Edition>
    <Edition>Pro</Edition>
  </VisualStudio>
  <VisualStudio Version="14.0">
    <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
    <Edition>Premium</Edition>
    <Edition>Pro</Edition>
  </VisualStudio>
</SupportedProducts>
...
```

Any idea how to make it appear in VS 2013 extension search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment there is a bug in the Visual Studio Gallery which stops extensions from being seen in 2013 if they have support for Dev14.  This has been going on for a few weeks now and there hasn't been any status updates on the issue (or a even a public acknowledgement that such an issue exists).

The best work around at the moment is to publish your extension on the gallery twice

1. The normal project without Dev14 support
2. A special temporary version of the project which supports only Dev14

This is the approach I've been taking with VsVim.

Comment: Has anybody reported this to Microsoft yet?

Answer (score 2):

A fix was deployed today which should resolve this issue.

Comment: Great, thanks for the update. :)  I'm planning to deploy this weekend and was hoping not to have to split.

Comment: I can confirm it seems to be fixed.  I published CodeMaid with VS2010, VS2012, VS2013 and VS14 support this morning and it appears as expected.