# Vsixmanifest supporting Visual Studio 2012, 2013, 2015

Tags: visual-studio, templates, itemplate

For a project I'm trying to create a set of development templates that hopefully can work on Visual Studio 2012, 2013 and 2015.

Google helped me a little bit and suggested to read this;
[vsixmanifest for all: VS 2010, 2012 and 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688715/vsixmanifest-for-all-vs-2010-2012-and-2013)

This implies to me that I should try to use Version 1.0.0 schema instead of 2.0.0 is this assumption correct ?

Other questions, do I need to specify all the product Editions of a version or is a single on enough ?

And does anyone have an example how to add 2-3 itemTemplates ?

This is what I currently have...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Vsix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2010">
  <Identifier Id="a452ff57-dc92-4db0-9ae7-9d45eb1cd405">
    <Name>My DevelopmentTemplates</Name>
    <Author>myName</Author>
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <Description xml:space="preserve">Some description for my DevelopmentTemplates</Description>
    <Locale>1033</Locale>
    <SupportedProducts>
      <VisualStudio Version="12.0">
        *<!-- are all version required to be specified, or is lowerst enough for all? -->*
        <Edition>Community</Edition>
        <Edition>Pro</Edition>
        <Edition>Premium</Edition>
        <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
        <Edition>Enterprise</Edition>
      </VisualStudio>
      <VisualStudio Version="13.0">
        *<!-- are all version required to be specified, or is lowerst enough for all? -->*
        <Edition>Community</Edition>
        <Edition>Pro</Edition>
        <Edition>Premium</Edition>
        <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
        <Edition>Enterprise</Edition>
      </VisualStudio>
      <VisualStudio Version="15.0">
          *<!-- are all version required to be specified, or is lowerst enough for all? -->*
        <Edition>Community</Edition>
        <Edition>Pro</Edition>
        <Edition>Premium</Edition>
        <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
        <Edition>Enterprise</Edition>
      </VisualStudio>
    </SupportedProducts>
    <SupportedFrameworkRuntimeEdition MinVersion="4.0" />
  </Identifier>
  <content>
   *<!-- how to add multiple ITemplates -->*
  </content>
</Vsix>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 1.0 schema is required to support VS 2010. As you support VS 2012+, you can use version 2.0 schema.

Lowest edition (Pro) is enough to support all higher editions.

You should specify Visual Studio versions 11.0, 12.00, 14.0 to support VS 2012, 2013, 2015.

Comment: works, version I have specified as followed; <InstallationTarget Version="(11.0,]" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />